# Проблема с Python, import telebot

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Захотелось написать своего бота для Telegram через библиотеку telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI).
Но вот столкнулся с проблемой, что, при попытке импортировать данный модуль в сам документ "import telebot" получается так, что для PyCharm этого модуля будто бы не существует. Пробовал переустановить Python, даже сам PyCharm после чего даже компьютер перезагрузил, установил модуль, устанавливается он без проблем и в pip3 list он есть, но вот все равно не могу его импортировать. Пробовал даже:

```
pip uninstall pyTelegramBotAPI
pip uninstall telebot
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Вот как отображается список, тут как видим телебот есть:

```
PS C:\Users\ryzen\PycharmProjects\NameSearch_bot> pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2022.9.24
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
idna               3.4
pip                22.2.2
pyTelegramBotAPI   4.7.0
requests           2.28.1
setuptools         63.2.0
urllib3            1.26.12
PS C:\Users\ryzen\PycharmProjects\NameSearch_bot>
```

Comment: Пофиксил.
Закройте тему

Comment: Как пофиксил? У меня точно такая же проблема(